# My Java GUI will not display when I hit run in NetBeans

Tags: java, jframe

I'm using Java, and I am trying to create a Calculator with NetBeans but my Jframe won't start.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Calculation;

/**
 *
 * @author rishi
 */
public class Calculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double firstnumber;
    double secondnumber;
    double result;
    String operations;

    public Calculator() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jtxtDisplay = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jBtn1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn16 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn17 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBtn18 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jtxtDisplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jtxtDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtxtDisplay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jtxtDisplayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn1.setText("1");
        jBtn1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn2.setText("2");
        jBtn2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn3.setText("3");
        jBtn3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn4.setText("4");
        jBtn4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn5.setText("5");
        jBtn5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn6.setText("6");
        jBtn6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn7.setText("7");
        jBtn7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn8.setText("8");
        jBtn8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn9.setText("+");
        jBtn9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn10.setText("-");
        jBtn10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn10ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn11.setText("9");
        jBtn11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn11ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn12.setText("0");
        jBtn12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn12ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn13.setText("+/-");
        jBtn13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn13ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn14.setText(".");
        jBtn14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn14ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn15.setText("/");
        jBtn15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn15ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn16.setText("*");
        jBtn16.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn16ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn17.setText("c");
        jBtn17.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn17ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jBtn18.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jBtn18.setText("=");
        jBtn18.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBtn18ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jtxtDisplay)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jBtn1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jBtn2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jBtn3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jBtn4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jBtn5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jBtn6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jBtn7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jBtn8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jBtn11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jBtn12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jBtn9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jBtn10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(jBtn17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jBtn15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(jBtn16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jBtn13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jBtn14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addComponent(jBtn18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jtxtDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jBtn18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jtxtDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jBtn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn1.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn2.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn3.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn4.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn5.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn6.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn7.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn8.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                     

    private void jBtn11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn11.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                      

    private void jBtn12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn12.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                      

    private void jBtn9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(jtxtDisplay.getText());
       jtxtDisplay.setText("");
       operations="+";
    }                                     

    private void jBtn10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(jtxtDisplay.getText());
       jtxtDisplay.setText("");
       operations="-";
    }                                      

    private void jBtn15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(jtxtDisplay.getText());
       jtxtDisplay.setText("");
       operations="/";
    }                                      

    private void jBtn16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(jtxtDisplay.getText());
       jtxtDisplay.setText("");
       operations="*";
    }                                      

    private void jBtn13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       


        double ops = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(jtxtDisplay.getText()));
        ops = ops * (-1);
         jtxtDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(ops));

    }                                      

    private void jBtn14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn14.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                      

    private void jBtn17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       String Enternumber = jtxtDisplay.getText() + jBtn17.getText();
        jtxtDisplay.setText(Enternumber);
    }                                      

    private void jBtn18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        String answer;
       secondnumber = Double.parseDouble(jtxtDisplay.getText());
       if (operations == "+")
       {
           result = firstnumber + secondnumber;
           answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
                   jtxtDisplay.setText(answer);
       }
       else if (operations == "-")
       {
           result = firstnumber - secondnumber;
           answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
                   jtxtDisplay.setText(answer);
       }
        else if (operations == "*")
       {
           result = firstnumber * secondnumber;
           answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
                   jtxtDisplay.setText(answer);
       }
        else if (operations == "/")
       {
           result = firstnumber / secondnumber;
           answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
                   jtxtDisplay.setText(answer);
       }
        else if (operations == "%")
       {
           result = firstnumber % secondnumber;
           answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
                   jtxtDisplay.setText(answer);
       }
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn11;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn12;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn13;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn14;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn15;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn16;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn17;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn18;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBtn9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jtxtDisplay;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Any console errors? If you had added the error, you may have gotten past the "you have provided mostly code" error you received when posting. Then you wouldn't have needed the "please help me fellas!"

Comment: What is the problem? How do you try to run it? Just tested and it is running...

Comment: The frame might be hidden by some other application.

Comment: Clean and rebuild the program

Comment: I dont have any errors in my code, when I run the project theJFrame window won't show up!

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine with eclipse you might see if the netbeans installed on your system is working correctly ,try reinstalling it.

Comment: Did you put this code in Eclipse and everything works?

Comment: Can you tell me something, how did u import this code in Eclipse?